# Create Waves Visulization Song Swift

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, beatsmusic, soundwaves

**Here is what I am trying to do:**

[image: Screen Shot]

**The screenshot is taken from a 6s iPhone.**

[image: Screen Shot]

I have been working in AVAudioPlayer and I would like to draw a waveform which looks look like the first screenshot. I am using [FDWAVEFORMVIEW](https://github.com/fulldecent/FDWaveformView) Github pods to draw waves. but I m confused how to draw same waves.

Code:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var soundWaveView: FDWaveformView!

  func createSoundWave() {
    soundWaveView.delegate = self
    soundWaveView.alpha = 0.0
    soundWaveView.audioURL = mainTrackURL
    soundWaveView.zoomSamples = 0 ..< soundWaveView.totalSamples / 3
    soundWaveView.doesAllowScrubbing = true
    soundWaveView.doesAllowStretch = true
    soundWaveView.doesAllowScroll = true
    soundWaveView.wavesColor = .lightGray
    soundWaveView.progressColor = UIColor.init(red: 46/255, green: 188/255, blue: 191/255, alpha: 1.0)
}

func waveformViewWillRender(_ waveformView: FDWaveformView) {
    startRendering = Date()
}

func waveformViewDidRender(_ waveformView: FDWaveformView) {
    endRendering = Date()
    NSLog("FDWaveformView rendering done, took %0.3f seconds", endRendering.timeIntervalSince(startRendering))
    profileResult.append(String(format: " render %0.3f ", endRendering.timeIntervalSince(startRendering)))
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {() -> Void in
        waveformView.alpha = 1.0
    })
}  

func waveformViewWillLoad(_ waveformView: FDWaveformView) {
    startLoading = Date()
}

func waveformViewDidLoad(_ waveformView: FDWaveformView) {
    endLoading = Date()
    NSLog("FDWaveformView loading done, took %0.3f seconds", endLoading.timeIntervalSince(startLoading))
    profileResult.append(String(format: " load %0.3f ", endLoading.timeIntervalSince(startLoading)))
}
```

Question: How to show the same waves as the original image(first screenshot)?

Can someone please explain to me how to draw same, I've tried to draw these waves but no results yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you would have to use a different library, which helps you display waves like the first screenshot. The library/ cocoa pod you're using: `FDWaveformView` will only give you waveform view like the second screenshot, unless it allows customisation of the waveform. There's no mention of customising the waveform view on the Github page though.

Comment: You might be interested in https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=Wave

Comment: TBH you could make the first waveform yourself, if you can get the audio values from the library, make a UIScrollview, set a max bar width, have a scrolling horizontal stackview, left aligned and add bars with a height constrant based on the audio value min/max

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah, waveform drawing... From the looks of it, you're probably going to need to fork this and make your changes, because the `FDWaveformRenderOperation` doesn't support this style.

It *looks* like you can modify the `plotWaveformGraph` method in `FDWaveformRenderOperation` to achieve this. Currently, it iterates over *every* sample in the buffer, but if instead, you maintain an `index` that's incremented every nth sample (the bar "width") plus the bar "spacing," you can get this appearance. This is a naive approach, to be clear. Ideally, you'd average the samples in a "bar" and draw that value.

This is NOT compiling code, but should give you a place to start.

```
let barWidth: CGFloat = 2.0
let barSpacing: CGFloat = 2.0

var x = 0
while x < samples.count { {
   let sample = samples[x]
   let height = (sample - min) * sampleDrawingScale
   context.move(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(x), y: verticalMiddle - height))
   context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(x), y: verticalMiddle + height))
   context.setLineWidth(barWidth) // note: stroke width straddles the path, so play with this
   context.strokePath();
   x += barWidth + barSpacing
}
```

Humble plug, but you can see how I do this in my [waveform drawing framework](https://github.com/cwalo/AudioArmada/blob/90f214d3d9483e817cdb1396e08f8f626a7be821/AudioArmada/Classes/WaveformZoomable.swift#L164). This is generally proof of concept and unoptimized. :)